# Providing small molecules to cells on a filter plate

Tags: cell-culture, assay-development

Lets imagine that I have mammalian cells that I've immobilized on a filter. Now I want to keep providing small molecules to these immobilized cells without resolubilizing the cells.

The caveat is that I would like to do so without fixing the cells or waiting for them to adhere to the filter. The small molecules are small enough to diffuse through the filter.

Comment: perhaps you can dip the filter plate in a medium containing the small molecules.. and then keep changing the bath after few days.. btw you want a batch or continuous system??

Comment: @WYSIWYG, Batch should be fine. The question is what would be the setup to do so. Would it be as simple as reversing a 96 well lid over and placing the filter plate on top? What about the wetting?

Comment: I am not very sure but you may try the plates used for growing ES cells over feeder layers separated by a membrane

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for these hanging inserts, for example: ["Millicells"](http://www.emdmillipore.com/US/en/product/Millicell%C2%AE-Cell-Culture-Inserts,MM_NF-C10504#overview)

[image: example of inserts]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on why this meets the OP's requirements?

Comment: The original poster would like to feed his immobilized cells small molecules, without fixing or waiting for adherence. The inserts contain a membrane, which forms a permeable barrier, to allow diffusion of small molecules, and site for attachment. The insert itself is free to move and hang in different culture media/wells, so no need to trypsinize or resolubilize them, and provides containment of the non-attached cells.